SOQL query Child to Parent
I have two standard objects (Case & EmailMessage) where EmailMessage has a lookup field to Case.
I'm using a simple SOQL query to get EmailMessage fields along with Case Status, but it is throwing and error.
This is the query:
SELECT Subject, Case.Status FROM EmailMessage LIMIT 50

This is the error:

Anyone know what is causing the error please?
Thank you

The relationship from EmailMessage to Case is called ParentId. See the Object Reference for Case
so your SOQL should be
SELECT Subject, Parent.Status FROM EmailMessage Limit 50


It is good now, thank you
